# Invalid column name '' when calling SaveChanges()

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have these generated classes:

```
public partial class BookCategoryMapping
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CategoryPropertyId { get; set; }
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public int OperatorId { get; set; }

    public virtual CategoryProperties CategoryProperties { get; set; }
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
    public virtual Operator Operator { get; set; }
}

public partial class Operator
{
    public Operator()
    {
        this.BookCategoryMapping = new HashSet<BookCategoryMapping>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<BookCategoryMapping> BookCategoryMapping { get; set; }
}
```

But whenever I call this method, with update false. I get

> Invalid column name 'OperatorId'

```
public void SaveBookCategoryMapping(BookCategoryMapping bookCategoryMapping, bool update)
    {
        if (update)
            _context.Entry(bookCategoryMapping).State = EntityState.Modified;
        else
            _context.BookCategoryMapping.Add(bookCategoryMapping);

        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

I have no idea how it can be invalid since both the classes are generated from the EDMX model.

EDIT: I have tried scripting an insert in SSMS. I acknowledges that the column is t here. But the insert still fails.

Comment: Can you verify that the column "OperatorId" exists on the database. Did you use Database First method when generating EDMX ? Cheers

Comment: @TKelly The EDMX is generated database first, yes. And I triple checked the database aswell. The column do exist :-(

Comment: Both insert and update routes crash? What SQL is generated? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @SteveGreene Both insert and update fails. The SQL generated is INSERT INTO Rules.BookCategoryMapping (CategoryPropertyId, GroupId, Value, OperatorId) VALUES ()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dropping the table and re-creating it fixed the problem.